# Sobel in C api and C++ api

Tags: opencv

I've just tested Sobel using C api and C++ api. But why is it different? All the parameters I used are the same.

[image: Sobel using C API] Output - using C API

[image: Sobel using C++ API] Output - using C++ API

**Edited**

C API :

```
/// Generate grad_x
grad_x = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(grayImg), IPL_DEPTH_16S, 1);
abs_grad_x = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(grayImg), 8, 1);

/// Gradient X
cvSobel(grayImg, grad_x, 1, 0, 3);
cvConvertScaleAbs(grad_x, abs_grad_x);
cvThreshold(abs_grad_x, abs_grad_x, 0, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY|CV_THRESH_OTSU);
```

C++ API :

```
cv::Mat img_sobel;
cv::Sobel(img_gray, img_sobel, CV_8U, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, BORDER_DEFAULT);

Mat img_threshold;
threshold(img_sobel, img_threshold, 0, 255, CV_THRESH_OTSU+CV_THRESH_BINARY);
```

Comment: can you please post some code for both C and C++ API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only 1 reason for different results. Data-Type!

In the C version, you are creating `grad_x` with `IPL_DEPTH_16S` depth. So each pixel has `short` data type. This increases the precision of the results which you get when calling the `cvSobel` function. `cvSobel` is able to accommodate a wider range of values (-32768 to 32767) in the result `grad_x`.

In the C++ version, you are not initializing the matrix and specifying the destination type `CV_8U`. The function `cv::Sobel` internally creates destination matrix of type CV_8U, calculates the results and then clamps them to the range of destination data type, i.e from 0 to 255. So all the negative values become 0.

To get the same results in C version, change the `IPL_DEPTH_16S` to `IPL_DEPTH_8U`.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. But all this time I thought it need to use 16S (after searching through the internet). So, which one is the correct way of doing it?

Comment: It depends how much precision you want. Otherwise, the "more correct" one would be the one whose precision is greater.

Comment: Thanks again for clarifying it. Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change last line of c++ code from
`threshold(img_sobel, img_threshold, 0, 255, CV_THRESH_OTSU+CV_THRESH_BINARY);`
to
`threshold(img_sobel, img_threshold, 0, 255, CV_THRESH_OTSU | CV_THRESH_BINARY);`

Comment: I don't think that is the cause.

Comment: Mizuki Kai, sgar91 - you are right guys. Sory for mistake, i just saw this difference and thought that this may cause the problem and post answer without analyzing the problem.